# Как правильно спроектировать приложение, в котором много текста?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

Возник большой вопрос, но у кого бы не спросил или не прочёл- везде разные идеи. Решать задачу разными способами- это конечно хорошо, но как будет лучше? Сейчас вкратце расскажу суть приложения. Имеется BottomNavigationView, на которой всего лишь 2 пункта меню(список и поиск).Всё организовано как надо-через фрагменты, но проблема заключается в том, что имеется большой документ(предоставлю его часть)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите, имеется определённый ключ и значение. Говорили, что можно использовать SharedPreferences, но как мне кажется, использовать столько текста в XML-файле неразумно, потому что текста там на 4 станицы. Предлагали использовать SQLite, но проблема в следующем: если на компьютере я создам готовую Базу Данных, а потом закину его в проект-ничего не выйдет или нужно будет писать определённый скрипт.
Моя идея заключается в том, чтобы добавить какой то готовый документ или сделать какой то XML-файл, чтобы я потом просто мог оперировать этими данными, но чтобы приложение не весило много и не долго подгружало этот текст из памяти например...Если что то описал некорректно- исправлю.

Читал книгу, в ней говорилось,что можно всё добавить в отдельный класс Java, а потом оттуда брать данные, но говорят,что в оперативке много будет храниться.Вот пример из книги.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за помощь! Думаю, проблему описал в полной мере.

Comment: android API позволяет работать и с XML и с JSON,  что именно вы хотите получить в качестве ответа?

Comment: мне нужно узнать,как и где можно хранить столько информации

Comment: Текстовый файл?

Comment: нет, нужно знать где хранить все эти ключи и значения,чтобы потом я мог их например через список вывести или реализовать простой поиск по ключу(вводишь цифры,а в TextView отображается значение или описание)

Comment: 4 страницы текста - это совсем не много. Закрываем тему... Шучу. PS: держите данные целиком в памяти, читайте/пишите в файл.

Comment: т.е. если я занесу данные в String.xml, например <string name="n1000">Денежные средства</string> и таких будет 100 и более штук,то это разве не будет считаться плохой реализацией?

Comment: Я бы создал базу SqlLite. Подключил бы к проекту и выгружал бы в Room. Так вы сможете доставать нужные вам записи по ключу, добавлять, удалять. Или подгружать новый файл с бд новыми данными. Вариаций использования будет намного больше)

Comment: @КотовНикита String.xml будет считаться плохой реализацией хотя можно сделать и так. Для таких вещей есть базы данных, например, SQlite как вам уже говорили, но работа с ней требует большего понимания кода чем работа со string. Так же Sqlite даст вам больше возможностей. И это будет хорошая реализация)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложу пару своих идей:
**1. Использовать файлы.** Название файла это ID (то есть избавляемся от номера оставляем только название раздела), в файле храните текст. По нужному ID (то есть по названию файла) подгружаем текст из файла (в контексте описной вами задачи был бы самый быстрый вариант).
**2.** Как было сказано в комментарии **используйте Базу данных**, но я бы не использовал SQLite считаю уже "устаревшей", рекомендую посмотреть бд REALM.
Вы написали что "...ничего не выйдет" что ничего не выйдет? почему вам нужно создавать базу данных на компе? а потом переносить в телефон? Создавайте сразу на телефоне. Обновляйте добавляйте все что хотите. Структура БД могла бы состоять из двух таблиц:
- id, title
- id, text
**3. Общий смысл задачи.** Если у вас есть список материалов у которого есть заголовок и текст, тогда опять таки не вижу проблем, сначала в список вы подгружаете все заголовки и показываете их пользователю (в этот момент текст не загружаете). После того как пользователь выбрал нужный ему заголовок вы подгружаете текст. + что бы это еще ускорить вы можете подгружать не весь текст (сразу все страницы), а только нужную страницу (например сначала первую).
**4. Что быстрей?** Попробуйте сделайте одну и ту же задачу разными способами узнаете ответ на ваш вопрос, да ресурсно-затратно но иначе вроде никак. Зато вы получите незаменимый опыт.

**Лично я считаю** что как бы вы не сделали, вряд ли, "ваших 4 страницы" будут загружаться дальше пару сотен миллисекунд, что для отзывчивости думаю нормально.
Вот откройте на телефоне целую книгу в программе FBReader или DjVuReader и подобных, у меня на устройстве книга открывается меньше секунды.
Сегодня, довольно мощные устройства и переживать из за скорости не приходится (если конечно задача конкретно в этом не стоит)